# Prevent call from interrupting if proximity wakelock is held

Tags: android, screen, call, wakelock, proximitysensor

I want to use PROXIMITY_SCREEN_OFF_WAKE_LOCK to turn off the screen if the device is near the face during a call. But it interrupts the call because of invoking onPause() and onStop() as soon as the screen is turning off on some Devices. For example it worked on a HTC One but not on a Samsung Galaxy S6. Do I need to handle the call in a seperate Service to prevent the interruption or is there a simpler way to get what I want?

If it's possible, I don't want to source out the call connection handling to a seperate Service because it would be a big effort. What's the common way to do it? When I think of Skype, WhatsApp, etc. I think it can't be an unusual use case...

This is the way I acquire the wakelock:

```
    int field = 0x00000020;
    try {
        field = PowerManager.class.getClass().getField("PROXIMITY_SCREEN_OFF_WAKE_LOCK").getInt(null);
    } catch (Throwable ignored) {
    }
    proximityWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(field, "My Tag1");

    proximityWakeLock.acquire();
```